# C & Android kernel module: what happened with f_flags here?

Tags: android, c, kernel-module, flags

I have a self-coded kernel module in Android which I open with `O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK`.

`O_NONBLOCK` is `2048` in both the user-program and the kernel module.

I checked that with

```
print..("O_NONBLOCK is %d", O_NONBLOCK)
```

in user- & kernel-space.

But now, when I try to check if `O_NONBLOCK` was set, I got a really strange problem:

```
static int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {

    if (filp->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK) {
        printk("O_NONBLOCK");
    } else {
        printk("NOT O_NONBLOCK");
        printk("O_NONBLOCK in my_open is: %d", O_NONBLOCK); // -> prints 2048
        printk("filp->f_flags in my_open is: %d", filp->f_flags); // -> prints 1, not 2048 or larger
    }
..
}
```

I tried something else:

```
cat my_device
```

but again, `filp->f_flags` is `1`.

I would assume maybe `0` for `O_RDONLY` but not `1` which means `O_WRONLY`.

Anyone an idea or explanation?

EDIT:

I also **don't** expect `cat` beeing `O_NONBLOCK`, but `O_WRONLY` is totally wrong.

I open it this way:

```
pcm->dfd=open(fname, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
```

and there's no `fcntl` later (and that shouldn't affect `my_open` at all. 
But of course I also tried to "re-set" `O_NONBLOCK` with `fcntl` without luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the userspace, indeed, passes what you think it must be passing. I find it hard to believe, for example, that "cat" would pass "NONBLOCK". It has no reason to.

Use strace on the userspace end to test what actually gets passed in.

Also, and a bit offtopic, are you sure you care whether O_NONBLOCK is set during open? Please remember that it may also be set using fcntl later on.

Shachar

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I will add additional informations on my question.